# Add the columns for the 2x4 multidimensional array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, sum;
    int a[2][4] = {{ 11, 15, 22, 7 }, { 12, 9, 16, 21 }};

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sum = 0;
   
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum = sum + a[j][i];
        }
        printf("\n%d", sum);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to switch `a[i][j]` to `a[j][i]` but it doesn't add the columns. I have no problems adding the rows. I also wanted each column to correspond with a letter. For example, the first column `A` would be `11 + 12`.

Comment: [i][j] must be in sync with index range. If i from 0-1 and j from 0-3 then order must be a[i][j]. To sum columns, you should switch the order of for loops. First, go through j than through i.

Answer (score 1):

Why two loops? One is enough:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sum = a[0][i] + a[1][i];
    printf("%d ", sum);
}
printf("\n");
```

If you want two loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        sum += a[j][i];
    }
    printf("%d ", sum);
}
printf("\n");
```

should work.

More problems

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also, declaring variables when needed is a good habit on modern C, and choose better names for your variables, i.e. prefer `row` and `col` over `i` and `j` and `table` over `a`. Finally, do not use magic numbers like 2 and 4 in the loops, they are prone to errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum {rows = 2, cols = 4};
    int table[rows][cols] =
    {
        {11, 15, 22, 7},
        {12, 9, 16, 21}
    };

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("%d ", table[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            sum += table[row][col];
        }
        printf("%d ", sum);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also would you have any idea if it’s possible to add another row but only contain letters? So that A corresponds with the 11+12 and B corresponds with 15 + 9, etc?

Comment: _So that A corresponds with the 11+12 and B corresponds with 15 + 9, etc?_ I don't get you, better if you fix your code and ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of sum to 0 before adding any other value to it. The C programming language does not initialize values to zero by default, you need to do it manually.

```
int i, j, sum = 0;
```

Also, the addition to sum should be written like this:

```
sum = sum + a[i][j];
```

Other than that, you do not need to use two loops, just add the previous line to the first loop, after printing.

Comment: The variable `sum` is set to 0 on each iteration of the first loop so there is no problem there, and `sum = sum + a[i][j];` is not what OP wants: _For example, the first column A would be 11 + 12._ the loops must be switched: `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) ... for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)` instead of `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) ... for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)`